# Importing Tensorboard for maskRcnn(Matterport - Mask RCNN)

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard

I am currently trying to implement Mask RCNN by following Matterport repo. I have a doubt regarding implementation of tensorboard.

The dataset is similar to coco dataset. Inside ***model.py*** under def train, tensorboard is mentioned as

callbacks = [ keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=self.log_dir,histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=False)

But What else I should mention for using tensorboard? When I try to run the tensorboard, it say log file not found. I know that there is something I am missing some where!!. Please help me out !

Answer (score 0):

In your `model.train()` ensure you set `custom_callbacks = callbacks` parameter.

If you specified these parameters exactly like this, then it means that your issue is that you do not properly open the logs directory.

Open (inside Anaconda/PyCharm) or a separate Python terminal and put the absolute path(to make sure it works):

```
tensorboard --logdir = my_absolute_path/logs/
```